# Why sqlalchemy don't make any inserts in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have  function:

```
def set_daily_amount_once(self):
    query = Session().query(AccountBalance).order_by(AccountBalance.time_valued).all()
    items = [item.__dict__ for item in query]
    merchants = [d['merchant_account_id'] for d in items]
    unique_merchants = [i for i in Counter(merchants)]
    all_merchants_and_generated_dates = []
    all_statements = []
    all_daily_statement_for_database = []
    for i in unique_merchants:
        merchant_and_generated_dates = {}
        date_start = self.get_ab_trs(i,time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))[2]
        date_end = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, "%Y-%m-%d")
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, "%Y-%m-%d")
        date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days+1)]
        date_generated = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in date_generated]
        merchant_and_generated_dates[i]=date_generated
        all_merchants_and_generated_dates.append(merchant_and_generated_dates)
        for date in date_generated:
            all_statements.append(self.get_ab_trs(i,date)[0])
        for statement in all_statements:
            daily_statement=DailyAccountAmount(
                merchant_account_id=statement['merchant_account_id'],
                date=statement['date'],
                balance_opened=statement['balance_opened'],
                balance_closed=statement['balance_closed'],
                debit_amount=statement['debit_amount'],
                credit_amount=statement['credit_amount'],
                total_amount=statement['total_amount'],
                currency=statement['currency']
            )
            all_daily_statement_for_database.append(daily_statement)
    try:
        Session().add_all(all_daily_statement_for_database)
        Session().commit()
        print('Must work!')
    except Exception as huston_we_have_problems:
        print(huston_we_have_problems)

    return all_statements
```

Probably, all `SELECT` queries are produced, but in logs I don't see any `INSERT` queries.
I haven't any exceptions, all code in `try` - work, but nothing added to DB.
What can be the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried printing/logging the value of `all_daily_statement_for_database` prior to calling `add_all()`? Perhaps it is an empty list?

Comment: @mhawke No, that's not empty list, I print that and it contain values, and new object of my class contain needed values. I try add records in `for`, but that's don't work too.

Comment: You (probably, you did not provide the definition of `Session`) create 2 different sessions. The instances are added to the first, the second commits. Try `session = Session()` and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not keeping a reference to your session and as a consequence it is being discarded:

```
Session().add_all(all_daily_statement_for_database)
Session().commit()
```

operates on two separate instances of `Session`, not the same one, hence the commit is not effective. Try this instead:

```
session = Session()
session.add_all(all_daily_statement_for_database)
session.commit()
```